# Terminate phone call in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone

Is there a way to terminate a phone call from an iOS app? The phone call will not be started by my app but needs to be ended by it.

Comment: I assume you don't mean "by xcode" but by your iOS app that you are developing in xcode, and I DON'T THINK YOU CAN DO THIS. And why do you even want to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there's no supported way to terminate a call programatically. You can get some information about calls using the Core Telephony framework, but [CTCall](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CTCall/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009590)'s `callState` property is read-only... you can't change the state of the call.

Comment: Ok. That's what I was afraid of. Thanks!